# Why does some line in result of ping include hostname?

Tags: ping

```
PING (ip) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from (ip): icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=22.3 ms 
64 bytes from (ip): icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=22.3 ms 
(hostname) 64 bytes from (ip): icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=22.3 ms 
(hostname) 64 bytes from (ip): icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=22.3 ms 
64 bytes from (ip): icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=22.3 ms 
(hostname) 64 bytes from (ip): icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=22.3 ms 
64 bytes from (ip): icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=22.3 ms
```

Comment: What implementation of `ping` are you using?

Comment: What `ping` command are you running to produce this output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Each time the ping command receives a response, it performs a rDNS lookup against the IP address. It would seem that your system sometimes fails on that lookup. To ascertain why, you would need to interrogate the DNS on that system, perhaps there are multiple DNS servers involved which not all of them have the correct info.

Answer (score 1):

That looks to be the default behavior of `ping`.  According to the [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ping.8.html), you can add the `-n` option to get numeric values only and not resolve host names.

Comment: I think the question shows an inconsistency in the output where some lines start with a hostname and others do not